# How can i get this constraint in a ER Diagram?

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, diagram

How can I get the third rule (the bold one) in an ER:

- A Teacher can help many Students and a Student gets help from many Teachers.
- A Teacher can lead many Students but a Student can be led by only one Teacher.
- The **Teacher can't help the Student whose he is leading**."

[image]

Maybe something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need do add a constraint between your Help and Lead tables.
Make sure the TeacherId - StudentID couple (?) are not in both tables.

Comment: Yes, i have a CHECK CONSTRAINT. I already have a funtional database. I want to build a Good ER diagram that show the constraint.

Comment: What about (0) between lead and help tables? (link to UML defining "no instances", in the Multiplicity paragraph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram)

Comment: Thanks, I like your idea, but that means to create a relationship between two relationships, right ? is that ok in ER Diagram?

Comment: Yes that’s the idea. A diagram is there to represent the need. If that is the need... I’m not a huge fan of formalism that doesn’t allow you to do stuff just based off principles.